# Published ES modules in an npm package, can't import

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an npm package that I published. I have it installed and the files are present and up to date in node_modules, but when I try to import it like so:

`import Message from 'discord-helper-lib';`

I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package
> 'C:\path\to\code\node_modules\discord-helper-lib' imported from
> C:\path\to\code\api\GameUpdater.js

The package itself has the following package.json:

```
{
    "name": "discord-helper-lib",
    "version": "2.0.2",
    "description": "Discord Helper Library",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "emoji-regex": "^9.2.2"
    }
}
```

and the class I'm trying to import is defined as follows:

```
export default class Message {
    constructor(text, messageReplyDetails) {
           //..
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I have to do to set up a module as an npm package to import it like others? Not sure if there's configuration or other requirements4

Comment: Do you have an index.js file in the main folder of your module? Which `exports` the things you want to export?

Comment: I think you need to add `"main": "Message.js"` to your package to indicate that message.js is the main file of your package

Comment: @ChrisG definitely not, do I need this? If so, would it be saying it can't find the package without that rather than the individual module?

Comment: @Midoelhawy I have many files I want to export, sounds like I would need to add index.js to export everything I want then.

Comment: I'm far from being an expert on this but when I look into a random module, I always see an index file and a "main" entry in the package.json.

Comment: @muttley91 you are right, but when in any case you need to specify an entry point to your package un less you don't have index.js in your package ...